# What tag to use for questions asking for studies? Currently we have "research", "evidence" and even "science"

Tags: discussion, tags

We have 8 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) tagged [research](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research).

We have 6 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence) tagged [evidence](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence).

We have 9 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) tagged [science](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science).

None of these tags has a tag wiki excerpt.

Both, [research](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) and [evidence](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence) seem to be clear tag synonyms.

With [science](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) it's different as this has a legitimate use teaching kids science concepts etc. But it has been used in the same meaning as [reserach](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reserach) and [evidence](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence) in one [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/30708/30519) before (that's also tagged [evidence](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence)), so I didn't want to leave it unmentioned. It probably only needs to be retagged.

Since tags are used to filter questions accordingly, having only one tag at maximum improves user experience.

Now, I see the following possible and sensible options:

1. We keep [research](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) (and [science](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) in its original meaning). [evidence](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence) becomes a tag synonym of [research](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research).
2. We keep [evidence](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence) (and [science](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) in its original meaning). [research](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) becomes a tag synonym of [evidence](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence).
3. We expand [science](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) to also include *asking for research* and both, [research](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) and [evidence](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence) become tag synonyms of [science](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science)
4. We declare these [research](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) and [evidence](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence) to be [meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and get rid of them entirely.

Which option do you like most or did I overlook one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I like your first option:

> We keep [research](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) (and [science](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) in its original meaning). [evidence](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence) becomes a tag synonym of [research](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research).

It seems to me that *evidence* implies research that supports a [behavior/other], whereas *research* is more open-ended as to conclusions, if any.

Comment: This is also my preferred option. And, as could be seen today, *evidence* might be used for questions about gathering evidence. I believe *research* is a bit more clear.